# Duvida em montagem de query com INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Eu tenho a seguinte query:

```
$conexao = connect();

$consulta3 = mysql_query("SELECT meu.id, f.idfollowed, eu_sigo.fname, eu_sigo.id, eu_sigo.profile, eu_sigo.photoperf, p.id, p.title, p.link, p.description, p.descr, p.url, p.photo, p.visivel, p.type, p.description, p.data
FROM u636623377_users AS meu
INNER JOIN u636623377_follows AS f ON f.idfollower = meu.id
INNER JOIN u636623377_users AS eu_sigo ON f.idfollowed = eu_sigo.id
INNER JOIN u636623377_posts AS p ON p.userid = f.idfollowed
WHERE meu.id = '$idperf'"); # id do usuário logado
```

Essa consulta ela pega todos os posts dos usuários que eu sigo, junto com mais algumas informações sobre eles, como nome, foto, e link do perfil que estão armazenados em outra tabela. Isso está funcionando perfeitamente. Porém, ela retorna apenas os posts dos usuários que eu sigo. Eu gostaria, que ela retornasse os meus posts também. O que devo implementar para que isso aconteça?

Estrutura das tabelas:

```
u636623377_follows = pastebin. com/i4QfJBBH  //junte os espaços

u636623377_posts = pastebin. com/tMUB5t5E    //junte os espaços

u636623377_users = pastebin. com/sabLHx97    //junte os espaços
```

Comment: Nao use pastbin, use a marcação do próprio stackoverflow, amigo, LEIA POR FAVOR: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve grato :)

Answer (score 1):

A sua resposta está no [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180026.aspx). Resumidamente você pode inserir outras queries no retorno mas elas devem retornar o mesmo número de colunas sendo do mesmo tipo.

Concatene o seguinte trecho:

```
UNION    

SELECT meu.id    
     , NULL -- f.idfollowed    
     , NULL -- eu_sigo.fname    
     , NULL -- eu_sigo.id    
     , NULL -- eu_sigo.profile    
     , NULL -- eu_sigo.photoperf    
     , p.id    
     , p.title    
     , p.link    
     , p.description    
     , p.descr    
     , p.url    
     , p.photo    
     , p.visivel    
     , p.type    
     , p.description    
     , p.data    
FROM u636623377_users AS meu    
INNER JOIN u636623377_posts AS p ON p.userid = meu.id    
WHERE meu.id = '$idperf'
```

Como são os seus posts, não faz sentido retornar informações dos seguidores e,  por este motivo, inserimos um valor neutro nessas colunas, neste caso NULL.

***UPDATE***

Deixei comentários ao lado dos NULLs para ficar visível as colunas que estamos tratando. Se quiser retirá-los, fique a vontade.

Answer (score -1):

Tente incluir um outro join na tabela de posts para pegar os seus posts,

```
$conexao = connect();

$consulta3 = mysql_query("SELECT meu.id, f.idfollowed, eu_sigo.fname, eu_sigo.id, eu_sigo.profile, eu_sigo.photoperf, p.id, p.title, p.link, p.description, p.descr, p.url, p.photo, p.visivel, p.type, p.description, p.data
FROM u636623377_users AS meu
INNER JOIN u636623377_follows AS f ON f.idfollower = meu.id
INNER JOIN u636623377_users AS eu_sigo ON f.idfollowed = eu_sigo.id
INNER JOIN u636623377_posts AS p ON p.userid = f.idfollowed
INNER JOIN u636623377_posts AS meusposts ON meusposts.userid = meu.id
WHERE meu.id = '$idperf' ORDER BY p.data DESC"); # id do usuário logado
```